# How to create a method with props passed to child component (Vue3)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am struggling on the last part of my starter project with outputting the results onto its own component.

I have created a method in the parent component to push the results to an array, and I am then passing that array as props to the child component.

If I just display the array in my child component it works fine, however what I am trying to do is then create a method in my child component based on the results passed via the props.

When I try to do this I am not getting anything outputted, is this something which you can do in Vue?

Parent:

```
<template>
  <button @click="decreaseCount">Decrease</button>
  <button @click="increaseCount">Increase</button>
  <div class="counterDiv">Counter: {{ count }}</div>
  <button @click="calculateResults">Submit</button>
  <results v-if="resultsVisible" :results="results"></results>
</template>

<script>
import Results from "./components/Results.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Results,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      results: [],
      resultsVisible: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increaseCount() {
      this.count += 1;
    },
    decreaseCount() {
      this.count -= 1;
    },
    calculateResults() {
      this.results.push(this.count);
      this.resultsVisible = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <div class="finalResults">Results: {{ this.resultsText }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["results"],
  data() {
    return {
      resultsText: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    returnText() {
      if (results < 10) {
        this.resultsText = "Below 10";
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I have created a very basic example of my problem below

[image: Edit peaceful-hoover-sfcon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should emit a custom event from child component which has as handler the parent method:

child :

```
<template>
  <div class="finalResults">Results: {{ this.resultsText }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["results"],
  data() {
    return {
      resultsText: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    returnText() {
      if (this.results < 10) {
        this.resultsText = "Below 10";
      this.$emit('push-item', this.resultsText )
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

in parent component :

```
<results v-if="resultsVisible" :results="results" @push-item="pushResult"></results>

...
methods:{
  pushResult(resulttext){...}
....
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to edit the codesandbox example? I cannot get it working still with your example :(

Comment: My answer is just a general solution for such situation, please  explain the exact scenario that you're trying

Comment: So when i pass the props e.g. the counter, I would like to write some text based on the value of the counter in my child component, the method i would like in my child component is: counter < 10 ? 'Less than 10'

Comment: do you mean the results length?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225516/discussion-between-shrewdstyle-and-boussadjra-brahim).